# How to load the last XML file and put in a dataset vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, readxml, xmldataset

I am stuck again. Please help if any of you can. I am really appreciate it.

I am creating XML files and load them back again. I use this following code to write xml to a folder. the code below will put date and time to the file name. and this code works fine.

```
    Dim filename As String = Server.MapPath("XML\" & SESSIONid & "_" & Replace(timenow, ":", "-") & ".xml")
    dSetPupil.WriteXml(filename, True)
```

Again, I want to load the last xml file back and put in a dataset. I normally write code like

```
    Dim dSet as new DataSet = ReadXml(Server.MapPath("AAA.xml")
```

But how can i find the last xml file and read it ?

Thanks xo much. Hope you guys having a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim strLastXmlFileWritten As String = String.Empty

Dim lstFiles As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("XML\")).GetFiles().ToList()

Dim dteCreated As Date = DateTime.MinValue

For Each objFile As IO.FileInfo In lstFiles

    If objFile.CreationTime > dteCreated AndAlso _
       objFile.Extension = ".xml" Then

        dteCreated = objFile.CreationTime
        strLastXmlFileWritten = objFile.FullName

    End If

Next
```

Comment: You are absolute genius NoAlias, I googled whole morning and couldn't find that out. thanks sooooo much.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.  I'm glad that it helped.  www.mdsn.com is a good resource for discovering the different namespaces and classes of the .Net framework.